# Adding specific name to a logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm setting up a python logger and I'm having trouble  having a specific name depending the file that it's calling the logger.

This is that I want to log in a file:
`2020-05-06 13:51:31,032 - myModule - WARNING - warn message`

Instead of `2020-05-06 13:51:31,032 - sLogger - WARNING - warn message`

This is what I have

```
import logging, logging.config

# set up logging
logging.config.fileConfig("config.ini")
logger = logging.getLogger('sLogger')

# log something
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

And my `config.ini`

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter,consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=sLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('logfile.log',)

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

I have seen code like `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` but this way it's not calling the `slogger`.

How can I have both things?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the name in the format with the filename.

```
format=%(asctime)s - %(filename)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

You can use any of the [attributes of the LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) object that python provides in the format.